# How to collapse Clojure docstrings in Spacemacs

Tags: clojure, spacemacs, code-folding

I am using [Spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/) to write a program in Clojure. I would like to be able to collapse docstrings. I've tried selecting the docstring and pressing `z a`, however, that ends up collapsing the entire function body.

Specifically, I would like to be able to turn this:

```
(defn flip-and-vectorize
  "Returns a vector with the arguments flipped so that

   `(flip-and-vectorize 1 2)`

   returns the following vector

   `[2 1]`"
  [a b]
  [b a])
```

into something akin to this

```
(defn flip-and-vectorize
  "..."
  [a b]
  [b a])
```

**Edit:**

Even being able to collapse arbitrary lines would be acceptable; meaning the collapsed version of the above function could look something like this:

```
(defn flip-and-vectorize
  ...
  [a b]
  [b a])
```

This would mean that the collapsing logic would not need to understand what a "docstring" was, but would merely collapse the selected lines.

Comment: I think what you mean is to do the opposite of narrow-to-region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. https://github.com/magnars/fold-this.el
2. https://github.com/mrkkrp/vimish-fold

Both these packages support folding regions. As in, it can fold whatever is selected. The difference is the latter has more features. Especially the ability to remember folds even if you close and re-open a buffer.

To use them, follow the instructions on their github page. But, when it says to run package-install, instead in spacemacs you want to open your `.spacemacs` with `SPC f e d` and add the package to your `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` as such:

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(fold-this)
```

Fold-this is more straightforward to setup, because it has less features.

In either case, you'll need to add your own keybindings. Or just select the region to fold, and go `SPC SPC fold-this`.

If using vimish-fold, you need to select the region to fold, and call `SPC SPC vimish-fold` to fold, and then you can use `` C-` `` thereafter to toggle the fold on and off. Or call `SPC SPC vimish-fold-delete` to remove the fold.

Comment: These suggestions do accomplish the goal, thank you!  However, the collapsed regions are not quite as neat as I had hoped.